# fstab ntfs-3g disk atime doesn't work

Tags: ntfs-3g

I have a extern USB drive connected to a raspberry. The drive is mounted in fstab using the following parameters.
/dev/sda1  /media/hdd  ntfs-3g defaults,exec,fmask=000,atime   0       0

The driver works perfectly, but there is only one small isue. The atime won't update. If i open a file with oxmplayer the time is still not changed.
I use ls -luh to see the files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, the local time was not set correctly. :S
It works great now.